# Validate form input, show popup if error

Tags: javascript

I have below a JavaScript function that is triggered when form is submitted. I want to check the price format and validate price between min and max. How to show a popup to inform the user that his input has wrong format?

```
function priceSetup(){

       var minPrice=document.getElementById("minPrice").value;
       var maxPrice=document.getElementById("maxPrice").value;
/// add checking here and show popup if something wrong???

    document.getElementById("priceForm").action="<?php echo base_url().MY_PATH; ?>getCategory/".concat(minPrice).concat("/"). concat(maxPrice);
    document.getElementById("priceForm").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = new RegExp(/^\$?[\d,]+(\.\d*)?$/);

if(price.test(minPrice) && 
   price.test(maxPrice) && 
   ParseInt(maxPrice,10) -   
   ParseInt(minPrice,10) > 0)
{
  //popup
} 
else
{
    document.getElementById("priceForm").action="<?php echo base_url().MY_PATH; ?>getCategory/".concat(minPrice).concat("/"). concat(maxPrice);
    document.getElementById("priceForm").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**One** way would be to add the event `onSubmit()`as follow:

```
<form id="priceForm" action="" onSubmit="return priceSetup()">
...
</form>
```

After that modify your javascript as follows:

```
function priceSetup()
{
   var returnValue = true;
   var minPrice=parseInt(document.getElementById("minPrice").value);
   var maxPrice=parseInt(document.getElementById("maxPrice").value);
   if (
        (parseInt(document.getElementById("Price").value) >= minPrice) 
       &&
        (parseInt(document.getElementById("Price").value) <= maxPrice)
     )
   {
      document.getElementById("priceForm").action="<?php echo base_url().MY_PATH; ?>getCategory/".concat(minPrice).concat("/"). concat(maxPrice);
   } else {
     /*... Code for showing a message ... */ 
     returnValue = false;
   }

   return returnValue;
}
```

A submit won't being done, until the function returns `true`.

Comment: I am using below code. But does not know why it always show invalid price format. It seems if else is not working even when I input correct format.

Comment: if(!isNumber(minPrice) || !isNumber(maxPrie)){
  alert("<?php echo $this->lang->line('invalidpriceformat'); ?>");
  returnvalue=false;
 }else if(Number(minPrice) > Number(maxPrice)){
  alert("<?php echo $this->lang->line('invalidpricerange'); ?>");
  returnvalue=false;
 }else {
  document.getElementById("priceForm").action="<?php echo base_url().MY_PATH; ?>getCategory/".concat(minPrice).concat("/").concat(maxPrice);
  document.getElementById("priceForm").submit();
 }
 return returnvalue;
}

Comment: Maybe while you wrote `!isNumber(maxPrie)`and not `!isNumber(maxPrice)`

Comment: YES YOU ARE RIGHT, THANKS

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted, in case it did answer your question. This will help other visitors in the future with similar problem